# Display stars from star rating using php loop in a function

Tags: php, html

I have a family recipe site that I am working on.  Each recipe has a star rating that is stored in a mysql database (integer between 1 and 5).  Currently, these ratings are displayed using html class=fa fa-star.  So 5 lines need to be added to the code to display 5 stars.  I want to dynamically generate these stars depending on the star rating in the database.  The recipe list page (desserts.php) calls a function (stored in another php file) to populate the list of recipes in the desserts category dynamically depending on the recipes stored in the database.

```
<!-- desserts.php -->
<!-- ##### New Recipe Area Start.  This section displays all recipes from the database. ##### -->
    <section class="small-receipe-area section-padding-80-0">

        <div class="section-heading">
                        <h3>Dessert Recipes</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <?php
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    list_of_recipes($row['recipe_name'], $row['recipe_img'], $row['recipe_link'], $row['stars'], $row['date_entered']);
                }
                ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- ##### New Recipe Area End ##### -->



<!-- recipe_list_component.php -->
<!-- ##### This function is called by desserts.php for every recipe found in the database in this category. ##### -->
<?php

function list_of_recipes($recipename, $recipeimg, $recipelnk, $stars, $recipedate){
$i = "";
$element = "

    <!-- New Recipe Area -->
                <div class=\"col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4\">
                    <div class=\"single-small-receipe-area d-flex\">
                        <!-- Recipe Thumb -->
                        <div class=\"receipe-thumb\">
                        <img src=\"$recipeimg\" alt=\"caramel_sauce\">
                        <!--<img src=\"img/bg-img/caramel1_thumb.jpg\" alt=\"\">-->
                        </div>
                        <!-- Recipe Content -->
                        <div class=\"receipe-content\">
                            <span>$recipedate</span>
                            <a href=\"$recipelnk\">
                                <h5>$recipename</h5>
                            </a>
                            <div class=\"ratings\">
                                <i class=\"fa fa-star\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>
                                <i class=\"fa fa-star\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>
                                <i class=\"fa fa-star\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>
                                <i class=\"fa fa-star\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>
                                <i class=\"fa fa-star\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>

                            </div>
                            <p>0 Comments</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        ";

        echo $element;

}

?>
```

In the function, I receive the number of stars recorded in the database ($stars).  I want to use this number to generate this HTML line <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"> which shows a star in the rating area.  I believe a For Loop is needed, but I am not sure how to generate the HTML statement so that if $stars = 4, I will see 4 stars for that recipe on the desserts page.

Thanks

Comment: Write a loop that makes `$stars` iterations and inside the loop output the HTML for the icon.

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 1):

Just repeat the string that number of times:

```
$element = "
--code--
<div class=\"ratings\">" 
. str_repeat('<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>', $stars) .
"</div>
--code--";
```

Or store it in a variable and use it as you use the others:

```
$star_list = str_repeat('<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>', $stars);
```

Comment: The solutions you mentioned worked great!!  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you very much.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Please mark accepted if it solved your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use a loop inside function

```
for($stars > 5;$stars--;){
    echo "<i class=\"fa fa-star\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>\n";
}
```

so your function must be like this

```
<?php
function list_of_recipes($recipename, $recipeimg, $recipelnk, $stars, $recipedate){
$i = "";
$star = "";
for($stars > 5;$stars--;){
    $star .= "<i class=\"fa fa-star\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>\n";
}
$element = "

    <!-- New Recipe Area -->
                <div class=\"col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4\">
                    <div class=\"single-small-receipe-area d-flex\">
                        <!-- Recipe Thumb -->
                        <div class=\"receipe-thumb\">
                        <img src=\"$recipeimg\" alt=\"caramel_sauce\">
                        <!--<img src=\"img/bg-img/caramel1_thumb.jpg\" alt=\"\">-->
                        </div>
                        <!-- Recipe Content -->
                        <div class=\"receipe-content\">
                            <span>$recipedate</span>
                            <a href=\"$recipelnk\">
                                <h5>$recipename</h5>
                            </a>
                            <div class=\"ratings\">
                                $star
                            </div>
                            <p>0 Comments</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        ";

        echo $element;

}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input.  You were able to help me resolve my issue.